# PHP JSON Array Get Value

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, decode

I need PHP JSON help.

I have current output :

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "response_msec": 15,
  "data": {
    "android": {
      "test1": 15,
      "test2": 6,
      "test3": 15,
      "test4": 101,
      "test5": 87,
      "test6": 8,
      "test9": 119,
      "test10": 101,
      "test11": 107
    }
  }
}
```

I need print this value : `test1 , test2 , test3 ...,test11 .`

I have tested some method :

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
$dec = (Array)json_decode($result);
print_r ($dec["android"]);
```

and

```
foreach ($array as $value)
{
   echo $value->android; 
}
```

But not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `['data']` key,

```
<?php

$json = '{"status":200,"response_msec":15,"data":{"android":{"test1":15,"test2":6,"test3":15,"test4":101,"test5":87,"test6":8,"test9":119,"test10":101,"test11":107}}}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump(array_keys($array['data']['android']));
```

Check here i have made a php sandbox http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f97a9bb499b54919b40d4d12f49049fdd732aef

Also, You can use the function `array_keys()` to get only the keys of an array, that's what i did.

Comment: Thanks You Very Much Best Reponse regards,

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if the json string is assigned to $value. It's just you forgot to include to get the data "data" from "value". Your 3rd line of the first method should look like this:
`print_r ($dec["data"]["android"]);`

Have a great day